# Is it possible to keep several files on windows partition after re-installing windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

Is it possible to keep several files and programs on windows OS after re-installing it? because of someone can steal the device that uses windows OS, then just removes the windows and install another one (cracked or even bought). So you just lose your device and all of the security applications! I think it is really secure-less and there is several methods that may security applications uses it for the times like this. So, Is it really possible to have and keep several applications on the windows even after re-installation?

Comment: If an attacker gains unrestricted physical access to your computer, there's not much you can do. If you're worried about sensitive data, you might consider a full disk encryption solution such as [BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/protect-files-bitlocker-drive-encryption#1TC=windows-7) or [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

Comment: I'm NOT asking about it. I'm asking about a method to keep my files and softwares on new windows that have been installed (after deleting old one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping files in Windows, none that I am aware of.

However, hard drives have a HBA area that requires a very low level tool to access.  The area is at the end of the drive and the HBA size can be increased.  Thus a number of files could be hidden there by manually using a program to write the files to the last sectors of the hard drive.  Then shrink the HBA to hide over them.

Unfortunately,  once hidden there would be no way to execute them.  However, you could put the name, address, and etc of the owner there.  Also you maybe able to have a lojack chip installed.

Comment: So what will happen to the security applications (like that allows you to control your device remotely and etc) that had been installed on the device? they will become unusable? if not, so what method they use to keep themselves usable even after re-installing windows?

Comment: They will be un-useable as they will be totally and completely hidden.  However, owner information could be hidden there.